# How to use the bitbucket source control on android studio?

Tags: android-studio, bitbucket

I know that this kind if question was ask before. 
But i looked all the old answers and there is nothing work.

I try to use the 'Plugins' of the bitbucket - but its don't work. 
I try to define the android studio code repository as GIT and define the bitbucket as the repository like i found in some manual - but still don't work at all.

Is there any way to do it ?

BTW: i have exist code and i want to check in it from the android studio.

Please any help.

Comment: You can always use GIT from command line. You won't get this kind of issues doing that

Comment: i know - but it will be better to do all ( check in/out/compare ) from the IDE

Comment: It is really easy to do that from command line. But it is your decision

Comment: :-)   thanks ... i want to do it as i said from the studio.

Comment: As far as I know, nothing ties the Git VCS controls to Github (or non-BitBucket sources) specifically. Then again, I've never put an Android app into anything other than Github...

Comment: Shouldn't this question be moved to meta stack? I mean, it's not about some programming error but is a valid topic for meta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact you don't need any plugins. First of all just enable Version Control in your project:

[image: Enable Version Control Integration...]

Then select `Git` in dropdown menu:

[image: Select Git]

Now open command line in your `Android Studio` and use following command:

```
git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"
git config --global user.email "MAIL@gmail.com"

git init
git remote add origin https://UserName@bitbucket.org/UserName/Test.git
git add --all
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

Next time, you don't need any command. You can do your works with menu buttons in `Android studio`.

**P.S**: In case of `gitlab` | `github` you just need to change your remote url to following:

```
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/UserName/Test.git
```

Comment: Sure :) I'm just saying that the question is asking about Bitbucket

Comment: sorry - i try but this is not solve the problem. i fail to upload my files to the bitbucket

Comment: @Yanshof what's the problem ?

Comment: @Yanshof I also edit my remote url a bit may solve your issue.

Comment: i  did all what you said - i replace the 'remote add' with my bitbucket path - and nothing in the repository